# InfluxDB docker image doesn't work with my Spring Boot application image

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I am trying to build an application using docker-compose --build command. However, I get the following error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 
'influxDB' defined in class path resource [com/order/app/config/InfluxDatabaseConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.influxdb.InfluxDB]: 
Factory method 'influxDB' threw exception; 
nested exception is org.influxdb.InfluxDBIOException: 
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:8086
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
    version: '3'
services:
  influx:
    image: influxdb
    container_name: influxdb
    environment:
      INFLUXDB_DB: test
      INFLUXDB_ADMIN_USER: admin
      INFLUXDB_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      INFLUXDB_HTTP_AUTH_ENABLED: "true"
    ports:
      - 8081:8081/tcp
  backend:
    container_name: order-app
    image: order-app
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - influx
```

And here's my InfluxDatabaseConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(InfluxDBProperties.class)
public class InfluxDatabaseConfig {
    @Bean
    public InfluxDB influxDB() {
        InfluxDB connection = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://localhost:8086", "admin", "admin");
        connection.createDatabase("test");
        connection.setDatabase("test");
        return connection;
    }
}
```

The application.properties file:

```
server.port=8080
spring.influxdb.database=test
spring.influxdb.url=http://localhost:8086
spring.influxdb.username=admin
spring.influxdb.password=admin
spring.influxdb.retention-policy=autogen
spring.influxdb.gzip=true
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong in my code? I'd be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your influx container and backend are running in two different containers that's mean that they are two different machines each machine has it's own ip.

you can't call influx db from your backend container by using `localhost:8086`

To reach influx db you have to call influx container ip or name or service name

also update the exposed ports in  influx to be `8086:8086`

in your case change `http://localhost:8086` value to be `influx:8086` and give it a try